# SerialException for python not working

Tags: python, pyserial, except

```
 def port_button(self):      

    self.ser = serial.Serial()
    self.ser.baudrate = 19200
    self.ser.port = port_id
    self.ser.timeout = 6
    self.ser

    try:
        self.ser.open()
        self.button1.configure(state=NORMAL) #allow button to be pushed
    except serial.SerialException:
        print "No connection to the device could be established"
        self.button1.configure(state=DISABLED) #allow button to be pushed
        self.Wrong_port()

    self.ser.close()
```

I am trying to write code that If I choose the wrong port for Serial Communication, it will display an error message, instead of the program shutting down.

I updated my solution and this worked for me!!!

Comment: Please don't tell us what the error message says, it's so much more fun to guess. Seriously, if you need help you would do well to provide as much information as you can.

Comment: This is part of my code. If I push a button, it will go to this function to establish Serial Communication. If I set the wrong port, I want the program to print an error message instead of shutting down

Comment: never mind I figure it out

Comment: Verna, I'm happy you have figured it out. In this case StackOverflow was your "stuffed bear" - explaining the problem let you think about how to solve it more easily. It would be really great if you took a moment to record the answer below, otherwise we are left in suspense.

Comment: Also, it struck me that my original comments might have seemed unfriendly. They weren't intended to be, and I shall try to be more welcoming in future. Everyone seeking knowledge about programming is welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: The code now is working code!!!

Comment: Can't argue with that, but what was wrong?